# Acceleration of stacked blocks on inclined plane with friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, friction

[image]

As shown in the Diagram, we have to find $a_1, a_2$ , Provided that, the surfaces are not friction-less, $\mu$ is the friction between the surfaces of plane and $M$ mass body, $\frac{\mu}{2}$ is the friction is the between the surfaces $M$ and $m$ bodies.

My approach was to make the free body diagram and indicating all the forces, according to me :
$(M+m)a_1=(M+m)gSin\theta - \mu(M+m)gCos\theta $
$ma_2=mgSin\theta-\frac{\mu}{2}mgCos\theta$.

But according to my teacher the answer is incorrect.
He says, While considering only mass $M$ block, the equation of forces shopuld be,
$Ma_1=(M+m)gSin\theta - \mu(M+m)gCos\theta - \frac{\mu}{2}mgcos\theta$

I considered the $M+m$ as a system, and so now I here omit the friction force between $M$ and $m$ because in this case it will be an internal force, and according to sir I cannot consider $M+m$ as a system because components are here in relative motion also by my equation he says the acceleration will be of centre of mass of both the blocks not the acceleration of the $M$.
Please consider both the equations mine and my teacher's and explain who is correct and how.
Now one more doubt is there was no relative motion between $m$ and $M$ then also, I think my equation will be same, am I correct in this also, or not ?

Comment: Hi Adesh and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: You have assumed that the two masses have the same acceleration but the diagram indicates that they have different accelerations.  So mass $m$ must be slipping relative to mass $M$.

Comment: Yes, according to me the acceleration is due to both masses, am I wrong here.

Comment: You can consider $M+m$ together, but the resulting acceleration will be that of the centre of mass. Your eqn for $a_1$ will be correct if the upper block does not move relative to lower block ($a_2=a_1$); otherwise wrong. New eqn not quite correct either : last term should contain $mg$ and should be + not - .

Answer (score 1):

You have not considered the frictional force acting on the big mass (M) due to the sliding of the small mass (m) on it. So your first equation should be;

(M+m)a1=(M+m)gSinθ−μ(M+m)gCosθ-(μ/2)mgCosθ

Comment: I have edited the question. Please Check.

Comment: The answer given by your teacher is incorrect (may be you have typed it wrongly). The  frictional force created by small mass on big mass should be (μ/2)mgCosθ  not (μ/2)cosθ. Teacher's answer is missing "mg". Check the equation in the answer that I have written.

Comment: Ok, that was a mistake in writing, but consider the mass taken for acceleration I took $M+m$ and he took $M$ only, in this aspect who is correct, and my reason not to consider the frictional force applies by the $m$ on $M$ is that i'm considering the $M+m$ as a system and in that case this will be the internal force.